2 rolls of the die summing game
This is the question: You have been chosen to play a game involving a 6-sided die. You get to roll the die once, see the result, and then may choose to either stop or roll again. Your payoff is the sum of your rolls, unless this sum is strictly greater than 6. If you go over 6
, you get 0
. What's the best strategy?
I have seen the typical approach to this problem where you establish a cutoff, $k$, establish a general formula and then plug in different values of $k$ to see which is the optimal value. Then the answer is $k=3$ i.e. re-roll if you have a $1$ or $2$, otherwise stop.
I wanted to try a different approach where you work out the expected value of always rerolling the die and use that to establish the cutoff value, $k$, however I am not getting the correct cutoff.
I get an answer of $\frac{35}{18}$ which means as per my argument, we should reroll only if we get a $1$ but if we get $2$ or more, we shouldn't re-roll.
This is my working out:

If our strategy is to always re-roll, let $Y$ be the earnings of the game and $X$ be the value shown on the first roll. Then our expected earnings, $E(Y)$ is:

$E(Y) = E(Y|X=1)P(X=1) + E(Y|X=2)P(X=2) + ... + E(Y|X=6)P(X=6)$

$E(Y|X=1) = \frac{2+3+4+...+6+0}{6} = \frac{20}{6}$

$E(Y|X=2) = \frac{3+4+...+6+0}{6} = \frac{18}{6}$
Similarly for the others I get:
$E(Y|X=3) = \frac{15}{6}$
$E(Y|X=4) = \frac{11}{6}$
$E(Y|X=5) = \frac{6}{6}$
$E(Y|X=6) = 0$
Then pluggin back into the original formula, I get $\frac{35}{18}$.
What is the flaw in my argument?

I don't understand the approach.  You have considered one strategy...always reroll (cutoff=$7$).  Unsurprisingly, that turns out not to be optimal.  I don't see how looking at this one strategy should dictate which other cutoff is optimal.

You appear to be analysing a different game ("you roll a die twice. If your score is $6$ or below, you win that amount; if more than $6$, you get nothing"). Not only that, but you're answering the question "what is the expected payoff?" rather than "what is the best strategy?".

What you should do is assume $X$ is the first roll and compute the expectation of the change in what you get from a second roll.  If $X=6$ the expectation will be $-6$.  If $X=1$ the expectation will be a little less that $3.5$ because you rarely go over.  Find the $X$ where this goes negative.

I realised the mistake I made. I needed to compare $E(Y|X=i)$ with $X=i$ itself where $i \in {1,2,3,4,5,6}$.
So if $i=1$, I would have needed to compare $1$ with $E(Y|X=1) = \frac{20}{6}$ and clearly it would be better to re-roll in that case.
Similarly for $i=2$, compare $2$ with $E(Y|X=2) = \frac{18}{6} = 3$, so again it's clearly better to re-roll.
Doing this for all of them, we get the same strategy - roll again for 1 or 2, otherwise stop.
